# Unable to reach tomcat server 9.x running on EC2 Red hat linux 9

Tags: tomcat

I installed Tomcat 9.x on EC2(Red Hat Linux server) and started the service. I'm able to hit the URL on port 8080 if I run the curl command on the linux server, but I'm not able to hit the tomcat server using the browser on my laptop. Please see the commands that I ran.

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-93-84 ~]$ curl -I ec2-3-93-63-56.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080

HTTP/1.1 200

Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Date: Sat, 21 Oct 2023 16:57:35 GMT

---

netstat -lnp | grep 8080

(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info

will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)

tcp6 0 0 :::8080 :::* LISTEN 3036/java

---

ps -ef | grep tomcat

tomcat 3036 1 0 17:21 pts/1 00:00:09 /u01/java/latest/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/u01/config/instance1/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /u01/tomcat/latest/bin/bootstrap.jar:/u01/tomcat/latest/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/u01/config/instance1 -Dcatalina.home=/u01/tomcat/latest -Djava.io.tmpdir=/u01/config/instance1/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

---

If I run the same curl command on my laptop, it does not work.

I tried hitting this URL -> ec2-3-93-63-56.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080
from a web browser on my laptop, but that also did not work.

So I'm not able to hit the tomcat web server remotely. From what little I know, port 8080 needs to be open on the linux server and it is open as shown in the second image shared below. If you know what is that I'm missing, please let me know. Thanks for your help in advance.

Note: I followed the instructions in the below article to install Tomcat on Red hat Linux.
[https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/apache-tomcat-9-installation-on-linux#:~:text=Create%20a%20user%20called%20%22tomcat,the%20new%20%22tomcat%22%20user.&text=Install%20the%20JDK%20from%20the,%2Fu01%2Fjava%22%20directory](https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/apache-tomcat-9-installation-on-linux#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20user%20called%20%22tomcat,the%20new%20%22tomcat%22%20user.&text=Install%20the%20JDK%20from%20the,%2Fu01%2Fjava%22%20directory).

I found the link below when trouble shooting. Step 4 mentions that I need to whitelist the IP range in the tomcat context.xml files. This was not mentioned in the first article. I tried this also, but it did not help.

https://tecadmin.net/install-tomcat-9-on-centos-8/

[image: EC2 Red hat linux server DNS]
[image: AWS EC2 Security groups that show port 8080 is open]

Comment: Please note that the public DNS changes each time I stop and restart the EC2 Red hat linux server. So the public DNS on the image that I shared does not match the DNS in some of my commands. This is because the commands are from yesterday and the image is from today. Hope this does not confuse anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to my problem. I had the HTTP protocol enabled in the security groups inbound rules. That defaulted to port 80 by default. Since Tomcat runs on port 8080(which is not the same as 80), I had to explicitly add custom TCP, port 8080 in the security groups inbound rules.